# Could not load file or assembly

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

When I am trying to debug in Visual Studio 2008, I'm getting the following error. I have cleaned the ASP.NET temp folder and restarted VS. I also removed the supposedly breaking reference and added it back. But nothing seems to work. Has anyone faced similar situations and is there a solution?

> Could not load file or assembly
>   '"GCS.Common (asif mohammed's
>   conflicted copy 2010-01-29)"' or one
>   of its dependencies. The given
>   assembly name or codebase was invalid.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)
>
> [FileLoadException: Could not load
>   file or assembly '"GCS.Common (asif
>   mohammed's conflicted copy
>   2010-01-29)"' or one of its
>   dependencies. The given assembly name
>   or codebase was invalid. (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x80131047)]
>   System.Reflection.AssemblyName.nInit(Assembly&
>   assembly, Boolean forIntrospection,
>   Boolean raiseResolveEvent) +0
>   System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(String
>   assemblyString, Evidence
>   assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark&
>   stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
>   +114    System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String
>   assemblyString) +28
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective)
>   +46
>
> [ConfigurationErrorsException: Could
>   not load file or assembly '"GCS.Common
>   (asif mohammed's conflicted copy
>   2010-01-29)"' or one of its
>   dependencies. The given assembly name
>   or codebase was invalid. (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x80131047)]
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective)
>   +613    System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory()
>   +203    System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo
>   ai) +105
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection
>   compConfig) +178
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler..ctor(VirtualPath
>   configPath, Boolean
>   supportLocalization, String
>   outputAssemblyName) +54
>   System.Web.Compilation.CodeDirectoryCompiler.GetCodeDirectoryAssembly(VirtualPath
>   virtualDir, CodeDirectoryType dirType,
>   String assemblyName, StringSet
>   excludedSubdirectories, Boolean
>   isDirectoryAllowed) +8809426
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileCodeDirectory(VirtualPath
>   virtualDir, CodeDirectoryType dirType,
>   String assemblyName, StringSet
>   excludedSubdirectories) +128
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileCodeDirectories()
>   +265    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled()
>   +320
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not
>   load file or assembly '"GCS.Common
>   (asif mohammed's conflicted copy
>   2010-01-29)"' or one of its
>   dependencies. The given assembly name
>   or codebase was invalid. (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x80131047)]
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ReportTopLevelCompilationException()
>   +58    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled()
>   +512    System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost,
>   IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory,
>   HostingEnvironmentParameters
>   hostingParameters) +729
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not
>   load file or assembly '"GCS.Common
>   (asif mohammed's conflicted copy
>   2010-01-29)"' or one of its
>   dependencies. The given assembly name
>   or codebase was invalid. (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x80131047)]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext
>   context) +8890735
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext
>   context) +85
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest
>   wr) +259

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> " * * * * * * * * 's conflicted copy with #### - ## - ## "

Seems like you are using **dropbox** to sync files, this "conflicted copy" files dropbox creates if 2 computers changes the same file offline.. and when they get online dropbox sync algorithms confuses which file is the right one so it keeps both files with renaming one to this name pattern.

In your case:

this happened inside your project's bin directory, just delete the file with "conflicted copy" part and keep the other one.. OR delete both if your project reference the dll from another location, and Rebuild the solution.

Comment: That was exactly the problem! So much for my idea of using Dropbox to sync to the laptop so I can work on the road!

Comment: Wish I could 1,000x up this!

Comment: Thanks also, this was my problem too. Dropbox must of created the conflict project files in the bin folder took me 2 days to find this problem..

Answer (score 12):

Assembly loading issues are something all .NET developers need to learn to fix. There are a number of possible reasons, to work out the problem there are two things you need. First understanding how [.NET finds assesmblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf.aspx). Second the [Fusion Log Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx) (`Fuslogvw.exe`), which with the knowledge of the loading process will allow you to identify what is working and failing.

Usually the reason to getting a load exception is that the assembly you want is not in the GAC or probing path. It can also be due to the target assembly not being built for the neccessary platform (e.g. a 64bit process cannot load an assembly built for "x86" only).

Comment: i had the same problem so i looked at build output and saw that it was building assembly witch was in the error message so i went to folder with and just removed that dll. it called like project_name.(some_date).dll
hope it can be helpful

Answer (score 3):

I was right. It was something that my version control software caused. When I got the latest version it somehow added an additional copy of all my assemblies with (asif mohammed's conflicted copy blah blah), after almost thinking about reinstalling in VS I just had to remove the sneaky dlls sitting in my file system.

Thanks for all the responses. Learned how to assembly loading works, so all is not lost.

Comment: I had the same problem, for me it was dropbox that caused it! I simply deleted the contents of my bin directry and rebuilded the application.

Answer (score 1):

Completely agree with Richard...
Just one more hint: reading the exception trace I think that "GCS.Common (asif mohammed's conflicted copy 2010-01-29)" is a very strange name for an assembly, isn't it? ;-)
Did you rename some file, perhaps in the bin folder?

Comment: i using version control so , the part in () maybe from that

Answer (score 0):

That does not look like a very good assembly name, but if in fact it does exist...

It seems that you are manually specifying this assembly somewhere, perhaps in web.config?

if so, try using the [Assembly Qualified Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname.aspx), an example would be found in your web.config for any assembly that microsoft places there. Do not worry about version/culture or key, just "type name, assembly name" will usually suffice.

e.g. instead of:

```
'"GCS.Common (asif mohammed's conflicted copy 2010-01-29)"
```

use

```
'"GCS.Common (asif mohammed's conflicted copy 2010-01-29), [insert assembly filename less extension here]"
```

p.s. my advice is to name assemblies using the same rules as identifiers in c#. your life will be easier in the long run.